Tampermonkey script works on MS Edge Developer Edition, regular Chrome, but not Chrome Developer edition
I'm using the same TamperMonkey script in:

MS Edge Developer edition 125.0.2492.1 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)
Chrome Developer 125.0.6396.3 (Official Build) dev (32-bit)  ... I just noticed that this is 32-bit
Chrome 123.0.6312.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

// @name         Show stuff
// @namespace    S-MF-OT.SBM
// @version      2024-04-01
// @description  Show stuff
// @author       me@thatplace.com
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {

   'use strict';
   // Your code here...
   alert("working...");
})();

The script runs in the 64-bit browsers but not in Chrome Dev 32-bit.  I just noticed that Chrome Dev was 32 bit as I was creating this post.  Is the script not running because Chrome Dev is 32-bit???
This is a heavily controlled corporate laptop. All browsers says "Your browser is managed by your organization".

---- EDITED ----
I was able to uninstall the 32-bit version of Chrome Dev and install the 64-bit version.  I'm shocked that domain policy let me do that, but it did fix the problem ... Tampermonkey scripts work in the 64-bit version of Chrome Dev.
